# How can I process more than 500 MB worth of images?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-compression, imagemin, mozjpeg

Code works fine when it's processing less than 500 MB worth of images. (I'm trying to do +25 GB worth) Is there a way to modify the code to get it to work with a larger quantity of images?

I get an error that looks like this:

> node:internal/process/promises:279
> triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
> ^
>
> [Error: EIO: i/o error, write] {
> errno: -5,
> code: 'EIO',
> syscall: 'write'
> }

or this:

> node:internal/process/promises:279
> triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
> ^
>
> Error: read ENOTCONN
> at tryReadStart (node:net:614:20)
> at Socket._read (node:net:625:5)
> at Socket.Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:487:10)
> at Socket.read (node:net:666:39)
> at new Socket (node:net:415:12)
> at Object.Socket (node:net:286:41)
> at createSocket (node:internal/child_process:328:14)
> at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:445:23)
> at Object.spawn (node:child_process:700:9)
> at execa (file:///mnt/d/Projects/GH_2022/imagemin-mozjpeg/node_modules/execa/index.js:84:26) {
> errno: -107,
> code: 'ENOTCONN',
> syscall: 'read',
> originalMessage: 'read ENOTCONN',
> shortMessage: 'Command failed with ENOTCONN: /mnt/d/Projects/GH_2022/imagemin-mozjpeg/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg -quality 75\n' +
> 'read ENOTCONN',
> command: '/mnt/d/Projects/GH_2022/imagemin-mozjpeg/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg -quality 75',
> escapedCommand: '"/mnt/d/Projects/GH_2022/imagemin-mozjpeg/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg" -quality 75',
> exitCode: undefined,
> signal: undefined,
> signalDescription: undefined,
> stdout: Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
> stderr: Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
> failed: true,
> timedOut: false,
> isCanceled: false,
> killed: false
> }

This is what I currently have:

```
import imagemin from 'imagemin';
import imageminMozjpeg from 'imagemin-mozjpeg';

import { promises as fsPromises } from 'node:fs';
import { promisify } from 'node:util';
import path from 'node:path';
import fs from 'graceful-fs';

const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);

const srcdir = 'images/source';
const distdir = 'images/dist';

imagemin([srcdir + '/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png}'], {
    plugins: [
        imageminMozjpeg({
            quality: 75
        })
    ]
}).then(files => files
    .forEach(async v => {
        let source = path.parse(v.sourcePath);
        v.destinationPath = `${source.dir.replace(srcdir, distdir)}/${source.name}${source.ext}`;
        await fsPromises.mkdir(path.dirname(v.destinationPath), { recursive: true });
        await writeFile(v.destinationPath, v.data);
    })
);
```

Comment: You can start by replacing the `forEach()` with a regular `for` loop.  `.forEach()` is not promise aware so your code is trying to run ALL the operations at once rather than one after the other.

Comment: `[Error: EIO: i/o error, write]`. Are you sure your hardware is okay?

Comment: @jfriend00 Could you show me an example? I'm not used to nodejs style javascript with all the async, await, promises, etc. Also where can you learn which methods are promise aware?

Comment: You could do batch processing or a sliding window approach similar as described in a [previous answer by myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71403393/17487348) which should give you quite high throughput by still being in control over how much memory is being used. The answer has nothing to do with image processing but the principle remains the same. Instead of issuing requests using `fetch()` you will be processing images.

Comment: @robertklep: I sure hope so!

Comment: @Mushroomator Yeah, I'll go try that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like imagemin grabs all the images at once before it ever gets to the for loop and crashes so I just made it so it process all the images synchronously.

So I made the following code. It's robust and can do as many images as needed in one go. It also replicates the folder structure to make things easy. Hopefully it helps someone else that wants to optimize a ton of jpeg files using the Mozjpeg encoder for their own images. (You can also easily change it for other plugins too if you want like `imageminJpegtran`, `imageminPngquant`, etc.)

Here's what I came up with:

```
// mozjpegify.mjs

import path from 'path';
import glob from 'glob';
import imagemin from 'imagemin';
import imageminMozjpeg from 'imagemin-mozjpeg';

const srcdir = 'images/source';
const distdir = 'images/dist';

Main();

async function Main() {
    GetPath(srcdir, GetPathCallback);
}

function GetPath( src, callback ) {
    glob(src + '/**/*', callback);
};

async function GetPathCallback(err, filePath) {
    if (!err) {
        for(let i=0; i<filePath.length; i++) {
            //console.log( filePath[i] + ' -> ' + filePath[i].replace(srcdir, distdir) ); // source -> target

            let ext = filePath[i].split('.').pop(); // get file extension

            if( ext == 'jpg' || ext == 'jpeg' || ext == 'png' ) { // make sure it's an image and not a folder or something
                await Optimize( filePath[i], ParsePath(filePath[i].replace(srcdir, distdir)) );
            }
        }
    } 
    else {
        console.log('Error:', err);
    }
}

async function Optimize( src, destFolder ) {
    const files = await imagemin(
        [src],
        {
            destination: destFolder,
            plugins: [
                imageminMozjpeg({ quality: 75 })
            ]
        }
    );

    console.log( src + '...Done' );
}

function ParsePath(filepath) {
    return path.parse(filepath).dir;
}
```